# Using ArangoDB through the command line not working

Tags: arangodb, arangoimport

Thanks for taking the time, so - Arango is installed and the WebUI has been working fine. I've been doing the tutorials and finished the basics, but attempting to move on and import my own data I'm getting stuck.

I stored my data in a google sheet so I exported that for ingest but then trying to access the command line tools to ingest it, I hit a hurdle of "command not found". Trying "arangoimport" for example as recommended [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangoimport-examples-csv.html), or "arangimp" and other recommendations I found online from a search. I also tried other command line tools and had the same issue.

Where should I be running this command from? (and how can I get there?) If the command can and should be run from the first terminal window I open, then please can you tell me what I'm missing and need to do :)

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example using your data as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? This would greatly help others answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and use cd to go to the directory in which arangoimport.exe is stored.
When the terminal is in that directory you can run the arangoimport command.

Comment: Or even simpler: write the command as path\to\arangodb.exe --file path\to\data.csv --collection name... etc. instead of writing it as arangoimport --file path\to\data.csv --collection name... etc.